# Authenticating a user using sessions with PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have setup some session code but it does not seem to be working!

On my login verification script for the POST request from the login form, my code is the following..

```
        if( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) )
        {
        // Perform Lookup
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM authentication WHERE email='" . $email . "';";
                $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                $fetched = $fetch['email'];
            if($fetched == $email)
            {
                // auth okay, setup session
                $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['email'];
                // redirect to required page
                header( "Location: app.php" );
             } else {
                // didn't auth go back to loginform
                //header( "Location: fail.html" );
                die("Failed to auth.");
             }
         } else {
             // username and password not given so go back to login
             //header( "Location: loginform.html" );
            die("NO Username or Password Given");
         }

        ?>
```

On my "Secure" page this is in the top..

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id();
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))      // if there is no valid session
        {
            header("Location: index.php?message=notauthed");
        }
        require 'includes/header.php';
        $name = $_SESSION['user'];
        ?>
```

On my Log-Out script this is in place..

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['user']);
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Woops totally forgot to include the issues haha :)

Login script works, redirects fine.

After logging in, I am unable to echo  $name = $_SESSION['user'];

Also, when I log out  I am still able to access the app page.

ALSO** I am running on PHP 5.3? I think. Not the latest, the hostgator php..

Comment: What's failing? Does the login verification script redirect you to the app.php page?

Comment: updated :) redirect works fine, auth with session doesnt.

Comment: "After logging in, I am unable to echo $name = $_SESSION['user'];": but you can have access to the secure page (which is app.php if I got it right?) without being redirected to index.php?message=notauthed?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Then login works. Maybe there's an "exit" or "die" in the file includes/header.php. Try a var_dump on $name instead of echo.

Comment: Now, it is not authenticating at all..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <?php
session_start();
session_unset($_SESSION['user']);
header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

This method is not the best because it only clears the contents of the variable not the session its self so, if you try to check for it again its still going to be present so instead try this:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
   header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Hope it helps.